# How to pass datetime from popup dialog to mvc controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

My requirement is when I click a button it should open a dialog where I can select dates, preferably start and end date. and on clicking ok/submit it should pass datetime to controller [HttpPost] action method.
This is what I have tried out...Unfortunately it didn't work

```
input name="ActivateBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Activate" onclick="opendatedialog()" />
<script>
    function opendatedialog() {
        $("#datepickerdialog").dialog({
            height: 300,
            width: 500,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            buttons: {
                "OK": function () {
                    var viewUrl = '@Url.Action("Activate", "User")';
                    $.post(viewUrl, new { startDate: $('.datepickerstart').val(), endDate: $('.datepickerend').val() });
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    return true;
                },
                "Cancel": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); return false; }
            },
            open: function () {
                $(this).siblings('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find("button:contains('OK')").focus();
            }
        });
    }
    $(function () {
        $('.datepickerstart').datepicker(
            {
                minDate: 0,
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
            }).datepicker("setDate", "0");
        $('.datepickerend').datepicker(
            {
                minDate: 0,
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
            }).datepicker("setDate", "2099/12/31");
    });
```

//UserController

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Activate(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    //TO DO
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Here On activate button click, the dialog with datepicker pops up. But afterwards ok button click does not do anything.

Comment: Capture the ok button on click event in a function and in that create an AJAX call post directed to your controller action passing in what you need. Each one of those parts is easily looked up for basic examples. You can spider off that based on your requirements. If you're using Razor markup and your JS is embedded in that and not in a separate file, you can easily create an URL.Action link to your controller for the call without worrying about the url path manually.

Comment: Do you need the user to be redirected to another page? Or you just need to call your action through ajax and keep the user in the same page?

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page. Your `return RedirectToAction("Index");` is pointless since ajax calls never redirect. If you want to redirect, make a normal form submit.

Comment: @Alisson It will remain in the same page. Basically a dialog will appear and close in the same page. The Activate action method is not yet complete. At this point the call itself not reaching Activate action method.

Comment: @Nard Can you provide a code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post(viewUrl, { startDate: $('.datepickerstart').val(), endDate: $('.datepickerend').val() });
```

This did work. I have removed "new"